# TFS multiple machines

Tags: tfs

How can I have the same user on multiple virtual machines be able to share the same workspace folder?  Should each user create a "public workspace" or should we change our practice?

A bit of background :

when we worked with VSS and VB6 / ASP each user would map to a  personal share (w:) which would map to \server\username\ . Every machine mapped w:\ to the user, so that when the user moved from one virtual machine to another they would find the state of checked in / out to be consistent.  (at worst they'd get a message from VSS saying you checked this out on xxx and now you're checking in on yyy... -> and they'd just click ok)

Now we're moving to TFS and we're finding that workspaces are specific to each machine (check out on machine A, and find that machine B is unable to edit)

I was looking at Public Workspaces, though that seems to be designed to resolve a different task I thought it might cover the issue...  So I was wondering if this was a safe practice and if anyone has actually tried it, or if we'd be heading for a major trainwreck.

Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted this. Whatever the details of Nick B's situation, I want to share a TFS workspace on an encrypted virtual disk across 2 virtual machines. But

Answer (score 2):

My analysis: Trainwreck.

Each user/machine should have their own local (ie: non-network) path for the workspace.

Comment: Thanks Chris, your response brings up an important point.  That we shouldn't be using network drives at all for workspaces.

I'm currently collecting evidence to support your advice though making changes to deep rooted company policy won't be easy at all.

Comment: IMHO, you want the developers working locally.  Whenever you find yourself introducing a number of workarounds just to get to the point of actually writing / debugging code a sensible person will realize that perhaps getting back to basics is a much better option.  Personally, I'd probably look at the reasons for putting up those barriers.  Usually things like this are the result of poorly thought out policies based on hearsay more than actual knowledge.